# Running a rails migration overwrites my charset. Any ideas why?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, utf-8, collation, utf8mb4

I have everything set to utf8mb4 in my DB :

````
mysql> show variables like "%character%";show variables like "%collation%";
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+----------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value              |
+----------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8mb4_general_ci |
+----------------------+--------------------+```
````

My database.yml [ I added encoding/collation *after* it was created ]. But I did however update all my tables and database to utf8mb4.

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  collation: utf8mb4_general_ci
```

When I run any `rails db:migrate` command, the export always looks something like this for every table :

```
-/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
+/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
```

I can check any of those individual tables and see that they are indeed utf8mb4 ( but only on some rows. Perhaps that's a problem? ) :

```
mysql> show full columns from ab_experiment_buckets;
+--------------------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field              | Type         | Collation          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          | Privileges                      | Comment |
+--------------------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| id                 | int(11)      | NULL               | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | select,insert,update,references |         |
| foobar_id   | int(11)      | NULL               | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| foobar_nam        | varchar(255) | utf8mb4_general_ci | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| foobar_index       | int(11)      | NULL               | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| foobar_probability | float        | NULL               | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| foobar_value       | text         | utf8mb4_general_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| created_at         | datetime     | NULL               | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| updated_at         | datetime     | NULL               | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| foobar_is_default         | tinyint(1)   | NULL               | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
+--------------------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? It's [utf8mb4 character set by default for MySQL database](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/33608) from Rails 6.

Comment: @eux rails 6.  i ended up reinstalled sql and mysql-client entirely and that has gotten me pretty much the rest of the way there..

Comment: Had to reinstall mySQL and now I'm in the same boat again.

Comment: Please show the query that exemplifies the problem.

Comment: Hey @RickJames, thanks for the reply and answer. The query itself is just `rails db:migrate` . The structure.sql that's dumped is basically what _my_ database is. But is it? Why would it be exporting UTF-8 if every single detail points to utf8-mb4.

Comment: @Trip - MySQL's "utf8mb4" is equivalent to the rest of the worlds "UTF-8"

Comment: in addition to encoding and collation try adding **charset: utf8mb4** to your database.yml

Comment: @David I believe that was clearly stated in the original question.

Comment: The diff shows a regression of changing from the  newer "utf8mb4" to the older "utf8".  Was that what you intended?

Comment: the goal is no diff. As my SQL config and database is on utf8mb4, and the code I'm pulling from is on the same. So the problem originates from doing a `mysqldump` in which my SQL config and database are ignored, and it dumps the SQL in utf8 format incorrectly. And presumably via an older version of mysql that I'm not even using.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something like this?

```
  def configure_charsets
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    suppress(ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid) do
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'SET NAMES utf8mb4'
    end
  end
```

and/or

```
dataSource:
    dbCreate: "update"
    url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/mydbname?useUnicode=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&autoReconnect=true"
```

The "UTF-8" above is deliberate; it should not be "utf8mb4" and vice versa.

Do you use `rake db:reset`?  It may cause trouble.

[Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) may help with a specific symptom.

Comment: Not particularly interested in monkeywrenching the output. I _did_ have it working by reinstalling my mysql-client in the past. But I bought a new M1, reinstalled all the same sql 7.5.3 and mysql-client 8. Exact same database. Literally just ported over. Same version sql and client. And back to the old problem again.

Comment: Since you're a SQL genius though. I think this is the big hint. `-/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 /; +/!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;` When I run the migration it's replacing the version min `50503` with `40101`. Which makes me think that the version of the client or sql is being either being misinterpreted, ignored, or I'm using a much older version ( somehow ) then I am led to believe. What would cause that rewrite other than an older SQL? I'm using versions mysql 5.7.36 and mysql-client 8.0.28

Comment: @Trip - The `SET NAMES` command was added in 4.1.1 ("40101"), but `utf8mb4` was not added until 5.5.3.  Either SET would be executed by 4.7 and 8.0.  What product generated `/!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */` ?

Comment: The product is Rails' ActiveRecord. And it would be specifically this file that is doing the ORM'ing https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb

Comment: Or if you're asking what product of mysql, the version is `mysql 5.7.36`

Comment: Ignoring Rails all together, if I do just `mysqldump` , I am still provided with the `40101`.. and not `50503` .. how would I make it `50503` ? What determines that number?

Comment: @Trip - If you are _loading_ the dump on mysql 5.7, the `SET NAMES` will be 'performed.  If you are loading onto the very old mysql 4.0, it would ignore that `SET`  (My "4.7" looks like a typo for "5.7".)

Comment: I found your answer here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137620/how-to-make-mysqldump-use-40101-set-character-set-client-utf8mf4 and it looks like you believe it is a bug that it exports this instead of `50503` for the version I'm using.